# What happens when I assign an object the value of a reference in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

void test(std::string &s) {
    std::string p = s;
    std::cout << p.length() << " " << p;
}

int main() {
   std::string s = "Hello world";
   test(s);

   return 0;
}
```

So, the function `test` receives a reference to my string `s` from my `main` function.

My question is, what does this line do:

`std::string p = s;`

Does it shallow copy the reference and put it in `p`, thereby defeating the purpose of using a reference in the first place?

Or does it (`p`) just act as a reference?

Comment: The copy constructor of the _lvalue_ will be called, if it's a _shallow copy_ depends on it's implementation. It's pretty unclear what you actually asking about.

Comment: It performs a deep copy if copy-on-write strings are disabled

Comment: Forget about "shallow" or "deep" copying. It just copies the object referred to by the reference. The semantics of the copy are whatever is defined for the type of the objects being copied (in this case, `std::string`.)

Comment: CoW is overcomplicating the question. Sounds like OP is asking about more whether initializing from a reference creates a reference (Python-style) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a copy of the value of the reference, it doesn't allow you to edit the content of `s` with `p`, to make `p` act as a reference and be able to edit `s` from `p`, you have to declare it as a reference:

```
std::string& p = s;
```

Comment: In other words, `std::string` behaves the same as `int` in this respect. That's one of the nice things about C++ is this consistency. `int p = i` would create a new `int`, initialized with a copy of `i`, so the questioner shouldn't expect that `std::string p = s` to be any different.

Answer (score 1):

> thereby defeating the purpose of using a reference in the first place?

Why does it defeat the purpose of reference, you have declared `s` as reference, isn't it? Not `p`. So as noted indeed it will copy the value which `s` contains.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when I assign an object the value of a reference in C++?

You cannot assign the value of a reference, or at least you should not think in such terms. A reference is not a pointer. What happens is that you assign the value of an object, because **a reference is the object**, accessed via a different name.

> ```
> void test(std::string &s) {
> ```

The fact that you are dealing with a reference is only really relevant at the point of declaration. All code in this function which uses `s` uses a `std::string`, not a `std::string &`.

> My question is, what does this line do:
>
> ```
> std::string p = s;
> ```

It assigns your `std::string` object to `p`, no more, no less. In other words, it does the same as it would in this program:

```
int main() {
   std::string s = "Hello world";

   std::string &s_with_different_name = s;
   std::string p = s_with_different_name;
   std::cout << p.length() << " " << p;
}
```

Or, even more simply, in this:

```
int main() {
   std::string s = "Hello world";

   std::string p = s;
   std::cout << p.length() << " " << p;
}
```